# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name: Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jetty, war

I am getting the following error stack when trying to deploy a war using a jetty server I have written.

```
INFO : jetty.StartJetty - starting jetty using war file ..\serialisation-preview-service\target\serialisation-preview-service-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
INFO : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - jetty-7.2.2.v20101205
INFO : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Extract jar:file:/U:/Code/Serialisation_Fresh/serialisation-preview-service/target/serialisation-preview-service-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war!/ to C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-serialisation-preview-service-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_-any-\webapp
INFO : / - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri May 22 09:02:37 BST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d75e99: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1958 ms
WARN : org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - FAILED jsp: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
INFO : / - Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri May 22 09:02:39 BST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [preview-service-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [dao-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [placeit.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [preview-server-overrideDEV.properties]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d61b48: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,myController,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,previewServerPropertyOverride,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer#0,labelService,placeit.SerialDataCSVGenerator#0,placeit.DataMatrixGenerator#0,org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser#0,printers,ftp.FtpEmulator#0,placeitPreviewProcess,placeitLabelProcess,placeitHapaProcess,hgdlCompiler,util.DateServiceImpl#0,org.springframework.integration.internalDefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0,poller,JobFileCreator,rendezvous,PreviewService,org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#0,org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0,writeFiles,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0,writeFiles2,limitJobs,org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter#0,writeJobRouter,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0,createJobFile,createJobFileSA,org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#1,org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#1,writeJobFile,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1,writeJobFile2,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileWritingMessageHandlerFactoryBean#0,writeJobFile2.adapter,org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#2,org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#2,writeFmtFile,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2,writeFmtFile2,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileWritingMessageHandlerFactoryBean#1,writeFmtFile2.adapter,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1,waitForReply,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3,generatedPreviewFile,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileListFilterFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean#0,generatedPreviewFile.adapter,org.springframework.integration.config.TransformerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#2,deliverReply,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#5,aggregationDaoImpl,notificationDaoImpl,parametersDaoImpl,serialisationDaoImpl,templatePreviewDaoImpl,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#0,org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate#0,dataSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,nullChannel,errorChannel,_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger,taskScheduler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d75e99
INFO : org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Initializing ExecutorService  'taskScheduler'
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d61b48: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,myController,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,previewServerPropertyOverride,org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer#0,labelService,placeit.SerialDataCSVGenerator#0,placeit.DataMatrixGenerator#0,org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpressionParser#0,printers,ftp.FtpEmulator#0,placeitPreviewProcess,placeitLabelProcess,placeitHapaProcess,hgdlCompiler,util.DateServiceImpl#0,org.springframework.integration.internalDefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0,poller,JobFileCreator,rendezvous,PreviewService,org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#0,org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#0,writeFiles,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0,writeFiles2,limitJobs,org.springframework.integration.router.RecipientListRouter#0,writeJobRouter,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0,createJobFile,createJobFileSA,org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#1,org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#1,writeJobFile,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1,writeJobFile2,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileWritingMessageHandlerFactoryBean#0,writeJobFile2.adapter,org.springframework.integration.transformer.HeaderEnricher#2,org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#2,writeFmtFile,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#2,writeFmtFile2,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileWritingMessageHandlerFactoryBean#1,writeFmtFile2.adapter,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#1,waitForReply,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#3,generatedPreviewFile,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileListFilterFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.file.config.FileReadingMessageSourceFactoryBean#0,generatedPreviewFile.adapter,org.springframework.integration.config.TransformerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#4,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#2,deliverReply,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#5,aggregationDaoImpl,notificationDaoImpl,parametersDaoImpl,serialisationDaoImpl,templatePreviewDaoImpl,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,entityManagerFactory,org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate#0,org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate#0,dataSource,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,nullChannel,errorChannel,_org.springframework.integration.errorLogger,taskScheduler]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d75e99
INFO : org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'myController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.TemplatePreviewDao controllers.PreviewHttpController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templatePreviewDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:609)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:491)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:432)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:432)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at jetty.StartJetty.main(StartJetty.java:56)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.TemplatePreviewDao controllers.PreviewHttpController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templatePreviewDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'templatePreviewDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:343)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:476)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:531)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:497)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:658)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:340)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'password' of bean class [org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean]: Bean property 'password' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1031)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
    ... 69 more
```

Here is the TemplatePreview class it complains about with an EntityManager define:

```
@Repository
public class TemplatePreviewDaoImpl implements TemplatePreviewDao {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;
    // ...
}
```

Here is one of my project context files with bean declarations:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="proxy" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistenceOracle.xml"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/DS_SERIALISATION"/>
    </bean>
```

And the contents of the properties file containing the information for the dataSource:

```
dataSource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@correct_url
dataSource.username=************
dataSource.password=************
dataSource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
entityManagerFactory.persistenceXmlLocation=classpath:/META-INF/persistenceOracle.xml
rendezvous.timeout=-1
```

The persistenceOracle xml file mentioned here is also accessible so I don't think it's a problem there. I have no idea why Spring cannot autowire the dependencies or why it is having trouble with my dataSource. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

*EDIT*

My override file exists in a separate project but I can't be sure my war project knows about it. The project that contains the properties file does not have a src folder or anything so I can't add it to the classpath of the war project.

[image: override properties file]

I pass DEV as a VM argument in my run configuration which gets appended when looking for the correct properties file.

Comment: What are you using to load the `application.properties` file? I suspect a [`PropertyOverrideConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html).

Comment: Hi @M. Deinum. I inherited this project so a lot of the code was already written. Are you talking about the properties file I mentioned at the bottom of my post? It is named after the war project I am trying to deploy 'preview-server-override.properties' I am not entirely sure what loads that. Perhaps that is my problem.

Comment: Well I'm quite certain it is... Read the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyOverrideConfigurer.html) I linked you to. Which should give you an indication why this is happening...

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the javadoc. Could you advise on the edit I made to the post? Apologies for my ignorance... I'm trying to get up to speed with this stuff as I go along.

Comment: Looks like you're creating an instance of JndiObjectFactoryBean instead of returning the jndi lookup.  What happens when you set the factory-method to getObject?

Comment: Could you elaborate on that @ConMan? Pretend I'm a child haha

Comment: Apologies, I'll write an answer, too big for a comment!

Comment: Thanks @ConMan Just a note on this... I am told that this all worked at one point but I don't have the original developer here to answer my questions. What I'm saying is that I don't think I need code changes per say... I feel like it is more of a configuration issue.

Comment: Is the jetty you're using the standard deployment environment or is it a local server just for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many things I decided to try this:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:"/>  
    <property name="username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
    <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="300000"/>
```

Seems to do the trick. Not sure why Jndi doesn't work :S

Answer (score 2):

What im thinking is that your dataSource is simply instantiating an object of type JndiObjectFactoryBean, then passing that all over the place until somewhere along the line Spring tries to inject the property "password", to which it finds that there is no property "password" for a JndiObjectFactoryBean object.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/DS_SERIALISATION"/>
</bean>
```

JNDI is an api which allows you to access a directory via names (see the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/)).  Instead of returning the JndiObjectFactoryBean object, it should be performing a JNDI lookup based on the jndiName that you are providing.

I think you need to tell the JndiObjectFactoryBean to do the look up and return the JNDI result as your Spring Bean.  Consider the below example.

Spring configuration:

```
<bean id="jndiLookup" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/DS_SERIALISATION"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mypackage.DataSourceLocator">
    <property name="jndi" ref="jndiLookup"/>
</bean>
```

Custom static factory to get object from jndi lookup:

```
public class DataSourceLocator {

    public JndiObjectLocator jndi;

    public static Object lookup() {
        return jndi.lookup();
    }

}
```

Theres probably a better way out there, but im no expert when it comes to jndi!

Comment: the JndiObjectFactoryBean returns a DataSource, but probably we need to see his JNDI Resource DS_SERIALISATION, i guess that one is either missing or probably misconfigured

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I really don't think I need to make a change that drastic. I know it is something silly but I can't put my finger on it. @user2248239 Do you mean to define a resource in the context.xml of the war project? 

e.g. 

<Resource name="DS_SERIALISATION"  /*Additional settings*/ />

Comment: I mean in the application Server or where you specified the jndi resource itself and Yen Something like <resource  ...>

Comment: Yeah, this is in my context.xml:

    <Resource name="DS_SERIALISATION"
      auth="Container"
   type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
      username="*************"
      password="*************"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@correct_url"
  />

I think this is essentially the same as putting it in the server.xml file for a tomcat server say...

Comment: Is the standard environment for deployment the same jetty you use? And if not can you test if it runs on your usual application server?

Comment: It is a local deployment on my machine. I have since tested running an older build of the war and it autowires everything with no complaints. I can't see any obvious differences between the 2 wars. I am rolling back to an older maven version that uses an older Java version to see if that makes a difference. I think the older war used this older maven. Clutching at straws...

Comment: @ConMan FYI: JndiObjectFactoryBean is a subclass of JndiObjectLocator so setting the jndiname property like I was doing above was actually doing a jndi look-up